# Control a fan motor (with PWM IC burned out)

Tags: pwm, coil, fan

After the IC fan controller burned out by a voltage error I pulled it out to see what the motor coils were like.

They are so I think:

*4 series coils, but I'm not sure if it's the 4 coils in series.*

[image]
Coils

[image]
PCB

[image]
Coils and fan

[image]
Where the coils are not found, so I think the 4 are in series.

I was sad because I had burned out the PWM IC of the fan.

I analyzed the 4 coils well, only two filaments are soldered on the PCB, soldered two wires as you can see in the image and plugged in a common 12v 1a power supply, it turned and stopped, so I was making contact and removed quickly it spun a few seconds and stopped.

I try use PWM pulse with the Arduino and a transistor, I can see the pulse in the scope that uses the sound card in my desktop PC but the nothing happens if I connect directly in a source of 12v 1a simply tries to spin and stop.

**NOTE:**

In the Arduino I tried different intervals for the pulse from 50ms to 2000ms. Possible to use IC 555?

I need help because I do not understand much about electric motors, both dc and ac.

Comment: include fan datasheet

Comment: Dc brushless model ksb0705hb, do not find datasheet. Sorry!

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Figure out if it is damaged?  Use a replacement without damaging it?  Repair this?  Run the bare motor with new electronics?

Comment: Methinks he was trying to fix a 5V fan that burnt out with 12V. Nice try but not a good question.

Comment: It works in 12v without problems with a 220r 3w resistor but I inverted polarity and chemo ic, and I want to take advantage of the bearing that makes up the fan. Making it work again using injected pwm, in this case I used the arduino but nothing working.

Comment: [This video](https://youtu.be/E9zM07v1vWk) may help to understand DC motor basics.  Your fan has to have at least two independent coils to set up a rotating magnetic field.  It may have four, to make the drive circuitry cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two H-bridges to do what you want to do. Wire the opposite coils together, and program an Arduino to switch the polarities at an adjustable speed, then give the fan a spin and try to adjust the switching speed to the point when it starts working. Look at the following schematic, voltage sources represent ends of H-bridges.

However, the Arduino controlled fan won't work nearly as well as the original one, as it needs to have some sort of speed feedback, which it doesn't, so spinning up is dumb luck. That's why you need to start it by hand and then the coils will pick up.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftlAly.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I had not thought of that, great.

Comment: But there are only 2 power wires and hidden circuits